# Combine vectors in R using vectorization where values only sum if they are not equal

Tags: r, loops, vector, vectorization

I have two vectors that I need to add together, but only in instances where their corresponding values are not equal.  Ex:

```
aa <- c(1,0,0,1,0)
bb <- c(0,1,1,1,0)
```

I want to generate a combined vector like so:

```
aa <- c(1,1,1,1,0)
```

How might I go about doing this, particularly with vectorization?

Comment: `+(aa | bb)` ...

Comment: Or `bitwOr(aa,bb)` of they are all 0s and 1s

Comment: `inds = xor(aa, bb); replace(aa, inds, aa[inds] + bb[inds])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to implement the `OR` gate .You can use `pmax` :

```
pmax(aa, bb)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0
```